# Unbalanced Data In Sklearn: When happens?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I´m using sklearn Logistic Regression package in a model with 88% of non-event and 12% of event. Always the predicion is tottaly zero, and I receive a accuracy of 88%. I think that data doesn't unbalanced enought to this, I tried predict the same database in SAS and I recieved a different answer. Which level of unbalanced sklearn has difficulty to lead?

Answer (score 0):

Generally if the data has more than 70-30 distribution than we can say that the data tends to be imbalanced. Now to solve the issue you can try out either under sampling(if the data is HUGE) or oversampling( i prefer this, using SMOTE library). This way you can cancel out the huge bias of getting 1 in the output. I hope you wanted to know how to handle imbalance data set. Right?